# elastic search GET/Multi GET vs idsquery

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In which case would one use an idsquery instead of a GET? What is faster/better practice?

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.idsQuery("typeName").addIds("1");
```

vs:

```
GetResponse getResponse = transportClient.prepareGet("indexName", "typeName", "1").get();
```

Do I only use the addIdsquery to prefilter querys?

Answer (score 0):

In `idsQuery` you can specify a list of types and ids, while in a simple GET you can only fetch one document - one type and one id - I think type is not mandatory.

Comment: I have found this post for you :) https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ids-query-vs-multi-get-api/42388

Comment: Yes but there is mget where you can have an array of ids, so the question is still legit. Thanks for the link anyway :)